# Header for download with space in filename

Tags: php

How do I set the right header if the filename should have a space in the name?

I tried

```
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=a fielename with spaces.txt");
```

but that gives only the suggested fielname "a" and cuts off the rest.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$file_name = 'a fielename with spaces.txt';
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
```

Comment: Why not just `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");`?

Answer (score 4):

```
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="a fielename with spaces.txt"');
```